# Moving Edges using a 4x4 Matrix

Tags: math, matrix

Is it possible to move only one edge of a rectangle using a 4x4 matrix transformation?

[image: Example]

Comment: This is off-topic. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Sure, if you represent that vertex as a 4-vector (when all you need is a 2-vector). May we inquire *why* you want to do it with a 4x4 matrix?

Comment: In processing, the only fitting function uses a 4x4 matrix, which operation would you suggest?
http://processing.org/reference/applyMatrix_.html

Comment: Suggest to move this to math.stackexchange.com

Comment: There's a *language* called "*Processing*"? Somebody should get a severe beating for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier than I originally thought.  You will have to extend your vertices into 4D vectors, if you want to multiply them by a 4x4 matrix.  To do this in 2D, you really only need a 3x3 matrix, but the extra dimension doesn't really hurt anything except perhaps the performance of your implementation.

Given your four points, Vn = (xn, yn, mn, 0), where n is in {0, 1, 2, 3}, and mn is either 0 or 1 depending on whether or not you want to move Vn from its current location.  To move the vertices you want moved by some vector (α, β) apply the following:

```
| 1 0  α 0 | | x0 x1 x2 x3 |   | x0+αm0 x1+αm1 x2+αm2 x3+αm3 |
| 0 1  β 0 | | y0 y1 y2 y3 |   | y0+βm0 y1+βm1 y2+βm2 y3+βm3 |
| 0 0  1 0 | | m0 m1 m2 m3 | = |   m0     m1     m2     m3   |
| 0 0  0 1 | | 0  0  0  0  |   |   0      0      0      0    |
```

Comment: So the function would be
applyMatrix(
1,0,30,0,
0,1,30,0,
0,0,1,0,
0,0,0,1);
For moving the edge by (30,30)?

Comment: Yes, that's part of it.  The other, equally important part, regards the mn elements in your extended vectors.  Each mn should be 0 if you want Vn to remain in its current position, and 1 if you want it to move.